# Mount a drive using a desktop shortcut instead of terminal

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, desktop, desktop-shortcuts

I'm currently mounting my shared drive using

```
cifs -o "username=${USER},password=${PASSWORD},uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)" //server-address/folder /mount/path/on/ubuntu
```

I'm trying now to run this command using a desktop shortcut instead of terminal so I did this:

1. Right click the desktop and create an empty file named connecttoshareddrive.desktop.
2. Pasted this into this file:

   `[Desktop Entry]
   Name=Connect to shared drive
   Exec=cifs -o "username=${USER},password=${PASSWORD},uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)" //server-address/folder /mount/path/on/ubuntu
   Terminal=true
   Type=Application`

But it's not working, and I don't know how to debug so I wonder what I'm missing?

Comment: `$(id -u)` is a shell (e.g. bash) syntax; your .desktop file is not a shell parser.

Comment: @IporSircer So is there a way to run this mount without using terminal?

Comment: of course; terminal **is not** shell. But you can run shell from .desktop, like `Exec=sh -c "<blablabla...>"`.

Comment: @IporSircer I tried changing it to `Exec=sh -c " Exec=cifs -o "username=${USER},password=${PASSWORD},uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)" //server-address/folder /mount/path/on/ubuntu"` but it didn't work